# Get rid of the "M" mark after file name in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know if it is a new feature in vscode. But I just want the "1" mark and the "M" mark after the file names disappear:
[image]
[image]

Does anyone one know how to turn if off?

Comment: thanks : )  problem solved by adding the line to settings.json: `"workbench.editor.decorations.badges":false`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Linux users:

add this line to the settings.json file of vscode:

```
"workbench.editor.decorations.badges":false,
```

---

For macOS Users:

thats coming from the git gui in macOS you can disable it by going to the settings and unchecking the "enable git" like this:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnlEq.png)

Doing this will not disable command line use of git cli it will only disable the GUI features provided by Vs Code at least as far as Ive tested.

Comment: It works the same for Linux, Windows or Mac. You could also set using UI. There's a separated setting for the badges on top bar and one for the badges on the file explorer tree.